# Htaccess two rules conflicting when trying to remove .php and create pretty URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to remove the `.php` extension at the same time as creating a "pretty URL" for a certain page.

I am trying to turn `domain.com/dox?id=3` into `domain.com/3`

Current rewrite conditions in my htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\$ /dox?id=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
# remove index
RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1/ [R=301]
```

This creates an error at `domain.com/3` that says:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /3.php was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

However if I add any extension to the code, it works. To explain what I mean, if I change the fourth line to this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.extension$ /dox?id=$1 [L]
```

Then the page `domain.com/dox?id=3` will be accessible at `domain.com/3.extension`

Obviously the problem is the two rules are conflicting, but not being a htaccess whizz, I can't figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /dox?id=$1 [L]
```

Or if id is just a number then this would be more appropriate:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ /dox?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much